# I am trying to do a cross join between two tables and eliminate duplications

Tags: sql

This is my query:

```
select ios_Subscribers.ID, ios_Eligibility.SUBSCRIBERID, ios_Subscribers.LNAME, ios_Subscribers.FNAME, ios_Eligibility.DESCR, ios_Eligibility.VERIFICATIONDATE`
FROM ios_Subscribers CROSS JOIN
     ios_eligibility
WHERE (ios_Eligibility.VERIFICATIONDATE = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-11-20 00:00:00', 102)) AND (ios_Eligibility.DESCR = 'WAIVER Advantage') AND (ios_Subscribers.Active = '1')
 ORDER BY LNAME asc;
```

Comment: So what is your question? What problem do you have?

Comment: I tried to use DISTINCT to eliminate duplications of the FNAME and LNAME, but get an error every time. I also want to eliminate NUL from FNAME and LNAME

Comment: *NULL from FNAME and LNAME

Comment: What error do you get? Please update your question with these details.

Comment: When I try to put the DISCTINCT command before any of the select items, I get a message like this "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Distinct:

```
select distinct ios_Subscribers.ID, ios_Eligibility.SUBSCRIBERID, ios_Subscribers.LNAME, ios_Subscribers.FNAME, ios_Eligibility.DESCR, ios_Eligibility.VERIFICATIONDATE`
FROM ios_Subscribers CROSS JOIN
     ios_eligibility
WHERE (ios_Eligibility.VERIFICATIONDATE = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-11-20 00:00:00', 102)) AND (ios_Eligibility.DESCR = 'WAIVER Advantage') AND (ios_Subscribers.Active = '1')
 ORDER BY LNAME asc;
```

Comment: I tried that, but I still get thousands of responses, a lot of duplicate fname and lname results

Comment: Thanks for the responses ... looks like the issue ;ies in our table, not the command.